# Как получить версию 4 (случайный) UUID?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, uuid

В [этом блоге](http://feuerthoughts.blogspot.de/2006/02/watch-out-for-sequential-oracle-guids.html) разъясняется, что значения возвращаемые функцией `sys_guid()` на самом деле не случайны на некоторых системах.

K несчастью, я работаю на такой системе.

Как получить случайный UUID?
Возможно ли это с `sys_guid()`? Если нет, то как получить достоверно случайный UUID?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [How to generate a version 4 (random) UUID on Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13951576) от участника [@ceving](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402322/ceving)</sub>

Полезные комментарии:

В общем, UUID не являются действительно случайными. – [@jpaugh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951576/how-to-generate-a-version-4-random-uuid-on-oracle#comment67816020_13951576)

Под "случайным UUID" я имел ввиду "тип 4 UUID". Думаю, здесь все понимают, что [псевдослучайность значит](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness). – [@ceving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13951576/how-to-generate-a-version-4-random-uuid-on-oracle#comment67816020_13951576)

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/13951576

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1138145

Answer (score 3):

Вот полностью рабочий пример (основан на ответе [@Pablo Santa Cruz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13951615)):

```sql
create or replace and compile java source named "RandomUUID" as
public class RandomUUID {
    public static String create() {
        return java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}
/
create or replace function RandomUUID return varchar2 as 
    language java name 'RandomUUID.create() return java.lang.String';
/

SQL> select randomUUID() uuid from dual;

UUID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
f83bf110-96e7-45d2-9abc-8ebabde8ee5f
```

Но лучше испольовать по возможности `SYS_GUID`.
Посмотрите ID 1371805.1 на MOS <sub>(прим. ред.: требует регистрации)</sub> - этот баг был исправлен в версии 11.2.0.3.

---

**Дополнение**

Какой из вариантов - Java или PL/SQL - производительней, зависит от того, как функция используется.
<sub>Прим. ред.: комментирование результатов сравнения производительности опустил, т.к. больше не соответствуют действительности.</sub>
Сравним на этом примере:

```
create table t1 as
    select level n from dual connect by level <= 10e5;

declare
    t number;
    c number;
    rawval raw (16);
    chrval varchar2 (36);
begin 
    t := dbms_utility.get_time;
    select count(*) into c from t1 where to_char(a) > RandomUUID ();
    dbms_output.put_line ('SQL/JAVA   elapsed '||(dbms_utility.get_time-t)/100);
    t := dbms_utility.get_time;
    select count(*) into c from t1 where to_char(a) > random_uuid ();
    dbms_output.put_line ('SQL/PLSQL  elapsed '||(dbms_utility.get_time-t)/100);
    t := dbms_utility.get_time;
    for i in 1..10e5 loop chrval := RandomUUID; end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line ('PLSQL/JAVA  elapsed '||(dbms_utility.get_time-t)/100);
    t := dbms_utility.get_time;
    for i in 1..10e5 loop rawval := random_uuid; end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line ('PLSQL/PLSQL elapsed '||(dbms_utility.get_time-t)/100);
end;
/
SQL/JAVA    elapsed ,01
SQL/PLSQL   elapsed ,01
PLSQL/JAVA  elapsed 50,67
PLSQL/PLSQL elapsed 40,21
```

---

В версии 4 значения GUID не *полностью* случайны. Некоторые байты имеют фиксированые значения. Не уверен, почему так сделали, или имеет ли это вообще значение, но в соответствии с [Generate a UUID compliant with RFC 4122](https://www.cryptosys.net/pki/uuid-rfc4122.html](https://www.cryptosys.net/pki/uuid-rfc4122.html):

> The procedure to generate a version 4 UUID is as follows:
>
> ```
> Generate 16 random bytes (=128 bits)
> Adjust certain bits according to RFC 4122 section 4.4 as follows:
>     set the four most significant bits of the 7th byte to 0100'B, so the high nibble is "4"
>     set the two most significant bits of the 9th byte to 10'B, so the high nibble will be one of "8", "9", "A", or "B".
> Encode the adjusted bytes as 32 hexadecimal digits
> Add four hyphen "-" characters to obtain blocks of 8, 4, 4, 4 and 12 hex digits
> Output the resulting 36-character string "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"
> ```

Значения, которые генерирует Java функция, по всей видимости соответствуют стандарту.

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13966531/6571020) от участника [@Jon Heller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409172/jon-heller)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Пока, как временное решение пользуюсь:

```sql
create or replace function random_uuid return raw is
    uuid raw (16);
begin
    uuid := sys.dbms_crypto.randomBytes (16);
    return (utl_raw.overlay (utl_raw.bit_or (utl_raw.bit_and (utl_raw.substr(uuid, 7, 1), '0F'), '40'), uuid, 7));
end random_uuid;
/
```

Функции необходимы `dbms_crypto` и `utl_raw`. Обоим нужно дать `execute` привилегию.

```
grant execute on sys.dbms_crypto to your_user;
```

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13956771) от участника [@ceving](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402322/ceving)</sub>