# Соответствует ли UUID возвращаемые функцией SYS_GUID () стандарту RFC4122?

Tags: sql, oracle, стандарт, uuid

Интересно, возвращает ли функция `SYS_GUID()` UUID, [соответствующий RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt)?

Например:

```
SQL> select sys_guid () from dual;

SYS_GUID()
--------------------------------
A6C1BD5167C366C6E04400144FD25BA0
```

Знаю, что `SYS_GUID()` возвращет 16 байт типа данных `RAW`. В БД используется `RAWTOHEX()`, и возможно `TO_CHAR()` для символьного вывода полученых ID.

Правильно ли интерпритировать символьный формат этих значений как совместимый со стндартными UUID:

```
A6C1BD51-67C3-66C6-E044-00144FD25BA0
```

Думаю, что нет, не соответствует стандарту RFC 4122 потому, что по определению действительные UUID должны указывать версию внутри себя. Например, для версии 3 соответстввующие RFC 4122 UUID:

```
xxxxxxxx-xxxx-3xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Соответствует ли UUID возвращаемые функцией `SYS_GUID()` стандарту RFC4122?

<sub>Свободный перевод [Is Oracle's SYS_GUID() UUID RFC 4122 compliant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6505837) от участника [@nulldevice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/819028/nulldevice)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/6505837/6571020

Answer (score 3):

Значения, которые возвращает `SYS_GUID()` *эквивалентны* UUID, глобально уникальны, но они не соответствуют RFC 4122. В [официальной документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SYS_GUID.html#GUID-761E36B4-32DA-497D-8829-3D4653381F9B) это соответствие никак не упомянуто:

> `SYS_GUID` generates and returns a globally unique identifier (RAW value) made up of 16 bytes. On most platforms, the generated identifier consists of a host identifier, a process or thread identifier of the process or thread invoking the function, and a nonrepeating value (sequence of bytes) for that process or thread.

Кроме того, значения идентификаторов хоста и процессов/потоков не оговорены в RFC 4122.

В англ. версии википедии о несоответствии явно говорится:

> The Oracle Database SYS_GUID function **does not return a standard** GUID, despite the name. Instead, it returns a 16-byte 128-bit RAW value based on a host identifier and a process or thread identifier, somewhat similar to a GUID